# How do I tell VS Code to run my python file in the correct terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I have two terminals open. In one of them, I have python activated (as I like to tinker with my python code). The problem is, when I attempt to run my python file, VS Code tries to execute it in *that* terminal (the one with python activated), so the file obviously does not run.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this annoying behavior?

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, but it seems if I simply choose to use the second terminal (the one on the right) for tinkering in python, leaving the first terminal deactivated from Python, I achieve my desired workflow.

Comment: why not edit your question

Comment: the top right arrow does not use your launch config, try `F5`